# brackets error in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try this function to display data in charts from database but when i build this code then this shows some errors

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var webmethod = "WebForm1.aspx/jqufunc";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webmethod,
            //data: JSON.stringify({ s: "xyx" }),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);



    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Computer info'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: eval(response.d)
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Figures'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Pentinum 4',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'Pentinum 3',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }, {
                name: 'Core i7',
                data: [6, 3, 4]
            }]



        });
    });


      </script>
```

this code shows some brackets error i try to solve this brackets but i unable to solve it any solution please

Comment: what use does eval have here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just go copying stuf form google without understanding what it does

Remove `$(function () {` properly close the success function,ajax function and document ready statement,remove eval

```
$(function () {

    var webmethod = "WebForm1.aspx/jqufunc";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webmethod,
        //data: JSON.stringify({ s: "xyx" }),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);


    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Computer info'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: response.d
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Figures'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Pentinum 4',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'Pentinum 3',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }, {
            name: 'Core i7',
            data: [6, 3, 4]
        }]



    });
  }});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not include `$(function()` inside `success`. It is equivalent to what you have included at the beginning i.e. `document.ready` in `jquery`. So the changes are as below:

```
$(function () {
     var webmethod = "WebForm1.aspx/jqufunc";
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: webmethod,
         //data: JSON.stringify({ s: "xyx" }),
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
              alert(response.d);
              $('#container').highcharts({
                  chart: {
                  type: 'bar'
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Computer info'
              },
              xAxis: {
                  categories: eval(response.d)
              },
              yAxis: {
                  title: {
                      text: 'Figures'
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  name: 'Pentinum 4',
                  data: [1, 0, 4]
               }, {
                  name: 'Pentinum 3',
                  data: [5, 7, 3]
               }, {
                  name: 'Core i7',
                  data: [6, 3, 4]
              }]
          }//success end. You were missing this
    });// ajax end here
}); //document ready end. Missing this too.
```

> Always indent your code properly so that you will know which
>   `function` ends where

Comment: i try this and always error show " Expecting more source characters "